# Issue Creating Kendo UI Grid Model with Navigation Property

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using the kendo ui grid and am trying to add CRUD operations for my model that has some navigation properties. Here is my schema:

```
 schema: {
                data: function (data) {  
                    return data || [];
                },
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Id: { editable: false,
                            nullable: false,
                            type: "number"
                        },
                        Frequency: { type: "string" },
                        FREQ_POOL: { type: "object" },//THIS IS A NAV IN MY MODEL

                    }
                }
            }
```

And here is my grid:

```
 $("#AFTRCCFreqGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: AFTRCCDS,

            columns: [
                //   { field: "Id", title: "Freq ID", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
                { field: "Frequency", title: "Frequency", editor: categoryDropDownEditor, format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
               { field: "FREQ_POOL.Comments", title: "Comments", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
                { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }
            ],
            toolbar: ["create"],
            editable: "inline",
            pageable: true

        });
```

When I hit the "Add New Record Button" in the kendo grid, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Comments' of undefined(anonymous function) @ VM2305:3kendo.ui.DataBoundWidget.extend._rowsHtml @ kendo.all.js:55504kendo.ui.DataBoundWidget.extend._renderContent @ kendo.all.js:56181kendo.ui.DataBoundWidget.extend.refresh @ kendo.all.js:56084jQuery.extend.proxy.proxy @ jquery.js:548Class.extend.trigger @ kendo.all.js:181Observable.extend._process @ kendo.all.js:8378Observable.extend._change @ kendo.all.js:8317jQuery.extend.proxy.proxy @ jquery.js:548Class.extend.trigger @ kendo.all.js:181Observable.extend.splice @ kendo.all.js:5371Observable.extend.insert @ kendo.all.js:7587kendo.ui.DataBoundWidget.extend.addRow @ kendo.all.js:53021(anonymous function) @ kendo.all.js:53086jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4665jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4333
```

Now here is the thing. I manually added a row to my SQL table, and I can use the kendo grid to **UPDATE** the row successfully. I can edit the navigation property "Comments". But for some reason, when I create a new row, I cannot get it to work.

My guess is that when I load the table it loads the navigation properties, but when I hit "Add New Record", it doesn't know how to create the navigation property "From scratch", whereas when I update a row it already has the navigation property info loaded.

Any ideas how I would go about fixing this? Thank you.

**Edit:**

On a side note, other grid I have that use similiar code don't have this issue, but when I add a new row to the grid and post, the navigation properties are null. The only time they aren't null is when I am editing. How am I supposed to "initialize" navigation properties when I create a new row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use template in this case. For the comments field, the code would be something like below :

```
{
      field: "Comments", template: function(dataItem) {
      return dataItem.FREQ_POOL["Comments"];
    } 
  }
```

I created a [jsbin to show how it fetches value from an object](http://jsbin.com/bivumolocu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Hope this helped